# How to structure MEF that sets label at runtime?

Tags: mef

I have a windows form with a label on it.  I want to set the labels value at runtime depending on which assembly is inside a directory.  I am not sure which code goes where:

`UI Form has a label.`

`2 class libraries that implement an interface.`

`Should I have another class that does the MEF composition work and do I need to call that in the constructor of the UI Form.`

If I need to call it at the forms constructor and I have many forms, does this mean I have to call it in very form.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `MEF` for the first time in a WPF application I'm developing and what you describe above is about how I managed my `MEF` modules.

Below is a summary of what I have done:

- Create a separate class for `MEF` composition. I named mine `Modules`. This class should do all of the `MEF` composition. You can either do the composition when the object is created or make a method for it. (`Modules.DoComposition()`)
- I create an instance of this `Modules` class in the constructor of my main UI window. Composition will be done at this time. (Create in the ViewModel if you are using MVVM design pattern.)
- I pass a reference to my `Modules` object in the constructor of any additional form that needs access to it. That way all forms will have access to your `Modules` object without needing to do composition again.